# Native debugging of external stripped shared library in Android Studio

Tags: c++, debugging, android-studio, java-native-interface

I have stripped and unstripped shared library.
How to load symbols while debugging stripped in Android Studio with LLDB?

I can successfully debug full unstripped .so located in "jniLibs" folder.
But it is too big, and deploying takes too long.

Specifying of symbols directory in Debug configuration doesn't work with standart and experemental plugin.

Answer (score 6):

You need to link your libraries with the "--build-id" flag so LLDB in Android Studio can find it instead of pulling it from the device. If your using the NDK toolchain just add the following to your linker flags:

```
'-Wl,--build-id'
```

You may also need to tell Android Studio where to look for the unstripped libraries (if you stripped the libraries yourself). You can do this by going to Run->Edit Configurations->Debugger Tab->Symbols Directories and add your path.

To check which library is LLDB using you can pause your app then go to the Native Debugger tab -> LLDB console and type:

```
image list
```

If your using ndk-build, just add the flag to the LOCAL_LDFLAGS in the Android.mk or just use NDK r12b or higher (the flag is enabled by default).

Comment: Works great in Android Studio 2.2.3 without needing to add a symbols directory, thanks